# Convert unique_ptr to void* and back, do I need to free?

Tags: c++, free, unique-ptr

In my code I use a library that has a function `store_pointer` accepting a `void*` and saving it in memory. There is then another function `retrieve_pointer()` that returns this `void *` to me, I don't have control over this library so I can't change how the function behaves.

Now I need to pass a variable to this function and get the pointer back, I have the code set up as follows:

```
struct Task
{
    int mId;
    Task(int id ) :mId(id)
    {
        std::cout<<"Task::Constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~Task()
    {
        std::cout<<"Task::Destructor"<<std::endl;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Task> taskPtr(new Task(23));
store_pointer(&taskPtr);

// do stuff that doesn't involve taskPtr

Task *new_taskPtr = reinterpret_cast<Task *>(retrieve_pointer());

// do stuff with new_taskPtr pointer
```

Right now this all works but I wonder if the `*new_taskPtr` pointer needs to be deleted or if the `reinterpret_cast` "restores" the pointer to a `unique_ptr` and so the memory will be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope/the program ends.

Comment: If `retrieve_pointer()` returns the exact pointer you gave to `store_pointer` then you should have `unique_ptr<int>* bar = static_cast<unique_ptr<int>*>(retrieve_pointer())

Comment: What are `store_pointer` and `retrieve_pointer`? Where is `void*`?

Comment: John, you'll need to make the example better in order for us to understand your question

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to run into problems since you're casting the result of `retrieve_pointer` to `int*`, but that's not what you passed to `store_pointer`.

Comment: This feels like this can derail really quickly if you're not careful. What happens if `foo` goes out of scope?

Comment: Ok i realize my really dumb attempt at explaining my problem had a lot of wrong things due to me writing it really fast, now I hope it should be easier to understand what i'm trying to do/ask. (The task struct is just an example I found because I can't post the whole real struct i'm using in my code)

Comment: @eerorika i changed it, I was writing an example really fast without thinking and said "screw it let's put an int" for some dumb reason, also I added some things in my question to better explain that these two functions are. sorry about that

Comment: @JVApen sorry for that, I was writing up something really fast and didn't think that you are not here with me to understand immediately what my question is :D i hope it;s better now

Comment: Should the line `store_pointer(&taskPtr);` be instead `store_pointer(taskPtr.get());`? That is, pass the address of the `Task` rather than the address of the smart pointer? Then reinterpret back to `Task *` instead of just `Task`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<Task> taskPtr(new Task(23));
> ```

When this variable goes out of scope, the dynamic allocation will be deleted. There is no need to, and you mustn't delete it yourself unless you call `release` on the unique pointer, which is the only way to transfer the ownership out of a unique pointer (besides transferring ownership to another unique pointer).

Any casts that you may do have no effect on this.

Comment: Follow-up hint: If you have applied this advice by @eerorika, you should go another step further and consider replacing the `unique_ptr<Task*>` construction from `new Task(...)` by a call to `make_unique<Task>(...)`.  (This thread is already quite old, so I mostly add this for readers that arrive here with similar problems...)

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a reference to unique_ptr:

```
store_pointer(&taskPtr);
```

As long as you don’t move the taskPtr or don’t mess with its internal pointer you are safe and don’t need `delete`.

Note that if `taskPtr` goes out of scope earlier than the user you will have dangling reference.

Comment: I chose eerorika answer because i think it's a little more complete, no hard feelings i hope ;)

Comment: @JohnSmith you just broke my heart ;). Just kidding, ofcourse you should choose the one that fits the best. It is important for ppl who read the question in future.